# has_one association works stand-alone but returns nothing, when used in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, associations

I know it's not the smallest question, but please be patient - I think I miss something, but can't figure out what.

```
class Company::ExpositionTarget::DiscretionaryNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company_exposition_target,
    class_name: ::Company::ExpositionTarget
end

class Company::ExpositionTarget < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :discretionary_notes,
      class_name: ::Company::ExpositionTarget::DiscretionaryNote,
      foreign_key: :company_exposition_target_id

    has_one :last_discretionary_note,
      ->(exposition_target) { where(company_exposition_target: exposition_target).order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) },
      class_name: ::Company::ExpositionTarget::DiscretionaryNote,
      foreign_key: :company_exposition_target_id
end
```

Each of defined associations work 100%. The one we are interested in is `has_one :last_discretionary_note`.

```
Company::ExpositionTarget.find(102).last_discretionary_note
```

Generated SQL:

```
  SELECT  company_exposition_targets.*
  FROM company_exposition_targets
  WHERE company_exposition_targets.id = 102
  LIMIT 1

  SELECT company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes.* 
  FROM company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes 
  WHERE company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes.company_exposition_target_id = 102 
  AND company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes.company_exposition_target_id = 102
  LIMIT 1
```

Which returns the expected result - last discretionary_note.

What I initially need:

**sort exposition_targets by the last discretionary_note.attribute**

To do the sorting I want to create a scope:

```
scope :discretionary_notes_available, ->(true_false) {
  joins(:last_discretionary_note)# more data selection based on true_false
}
```

## Now the problem:

`Company::ExpositionTarget.joins(:last_discretionary_note)` **returns nothing**.

Generated SQL:

```
  SELECT company_exposition_targets.*
  FROM company_exposition_targets
  INNER JOIN company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes
  ON company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes.company_exposition_target_id = company_exposition_targets.id 
  AND company_exposition_target_discretionary_notes.company_exposition_target_id = NULL
```

This query is wrong and does not take into account the definition of `has_one: last_discretionary_note`.

## QUESTION:

**Why does AR not treating the has_one association correctly in scope? And, what is more important - where is my mistake and how do I achieve what I need?**

Again, schematically I need the following:

```
scope :discretionary_notes_available, ->(true_false) {
  select all company_exposition_targets where company_exposition_targets.discretionary_notes.last.allow_participant_to_download_pdf = true_false
}
```

Comment: oh really, downvote? may be tell me why, silent guy :)

Comment: yeah strange, upvoted you again... sorry that I have nothing to contribute :)

Comment: What AR version do you have? Have you tried to reproduce it with a smaller code, similar to the https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_master.rb ?

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin I think I created an issue on Github back then, but AFAIR did not have time to reproduce it and found some workaround..